# Get IndexPath.Row from TableView Objective C

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, cell, nsindexpath

Before asking this question, I searched a lot on Google and Stackoverflow. Tried also some examples, but I can't make the function work.

Since the hierarchy of the tableview is changed since iOS 7, is it kind of hard to find a solution.

I got a standard tableview with a couple items and one button on the screen.

I need to get the indexPath.row number when selecting an item from the tableview and clicking on the button.

This is my code

```
- (IBAction)buttonGetNumber:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[(UIView *)[button superview] superview]];
    NSLog(@"%i", indexPath.row);
}
```

This keeps returning a '0', no matter which item I select from the tableview.

I also tried this (2):

```
- (IBAction)buttonGetNumber:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [[button superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *index = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"%i", index.row);
}
```

This also returns a '0'.

I also tried this (3):

```
- (IBAction)buttonGetNumber:(id)sender {
    UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *buttonCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[senderButton superview] superview];
    UITableView* table = (UITableView *)[buttonCell superview];
    NSIndexPath* pathOfTheCell = [table indexPathForCell:buttonCell];
    NSInteger rowOfTheCell = [pathOfTheCell row];
    NSLog(@"%i", rowOfTheCell);
}
```

And this makes the application crash.

Any clue how I can solve this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried (UITableView *)[[buttonCell superview] superview]; you have provided on example 3?

Comment: As per the linked duplicate question, the preferred way to do this is to set the button's `tag` property to the table row number in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: @Darren: I am not sure about that. As Paul Heller commented in the linked question, the tag methods fails if rows are inserted or deleted. Actually I like the "convertToPoint" method of drexel sharp (also given below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an instance variable `_lastClickedRow` Set it with tableview delegate like below. And when you click the to "Get Row" button use _lastClickedRow.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    _lastClickedRow = indexPath.row;
}

- (IBAction)buttonGetNumber:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"%d" , _lastClickedRow);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In this case 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' is the delegate, am I right?

Comment: what if don't call from didselect method.but i want know indexpath.row from button which is in tableview.any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason selected cell doesn't work for you (e.g. for a multiple selection case), you could get row from sender's frame:

```
- (IBAction)buttonGetNumber:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonOrigin = sender.frame.origin;
    CGPoint pointInTableview = [self.tableView convertPoint:buttonOrigin fromView:sender.superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInTableview];
    if (indexPath) {
        // Do your work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply set the `tag` of the `UIButton` same as the `indexPath.row` using:

```
yourButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

in `didSelectRowForIndexPath:`.

Then in buttonGetNumber: method, you get the row number using:

```
int rowNum = [(UIButton*)sender tag];
```

Here, you have the advantage of not using any third variable.

Comment: if i have multiple tablview than how to know return row is from specific table?

Comment: At the top my head, I would do it like this : iterate over `superview`s of your button, until you reach a view that is `isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]`. You can get the relevant `tableView` that way.

Comment: i am not using didselect method (used  custom method) .and one more thing i am not using customtableview. so isKindOfClass:[UITableView class] is working ?

Comment: Yes it works. As long as your custom view is a table view (subclassed), `isKindOfClass...` will work right. For example `[aView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]` will work fine for `UITextField`s, `UITableView`s, `UILabel`s etc, all of which inherit from `UIView`.